# mysql-workbench: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, linux, bash, mysql-workbench, dependencias

Estoy tratando de iniciar `mysql-workbench`... La respuesta es la siguiente:

```sh
method return time=1623786822.881780 sender=:1.436 -> destination=:1.618 serial=40 reply_serial=2
   string "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
                      "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<!-- GDBus 2.64.3 -->
<node>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties">
    <method name="Get">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="property_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="value" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetAll">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="properties" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Set">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="property_name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="value" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="PropertiesChanged">
      <arg type="s" name="interface_name"/>
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="changed_properties"/>
      <arg type="as" name="invalidated_properties"/>
    </signal>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable">
    <method name="Introspect">
      <arg type="s" name="xml_data" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer">
    <method name="Ping"/>
    <method name="GetMachineId">
      <arg type="s" name="machine_uuid" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.gnome.keyring.InternalUnsupportedGuiltRiddenInterface">
    <method name="ChangeWithMasterPassword">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="original" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="master" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ChangeWithPrompt">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="CreateWithMasterPassword">
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="attributes" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="master" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="UnlockWithMasterPassword">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="(oayays)" name="master" direction="in"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.Secret.Service">
    <method name="OpenSession">
      <arg type="s" name="algorithm" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="input" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="v" name="output" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="result" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="CreateCollection">
      <arg type="a{sv}" name="properties" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="s" name="alias" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SearchItems">
      <arg type="a{ss}" name="attributes" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="unlocked" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="locked" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Unlock">
      <arg type="ao" name="objects" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="unlocked" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="Lock">
      <arg type="ao" name="objects" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="ao" name="locked" direction="out"/>
      <arg type="o" name="Prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="LockService"/>
    <method name="ChangeLock">
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="prompt" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetSecrets">
      <arg type="ao" name="items" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="session" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="a{o(oayays)}" name="secrets" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="ReadAlias">
      <arg type="s" name="name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="out"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SetAlias">
      <arg type="s" name="name" direction="in"/>
      <arg type="o" name="collection" direction="in"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="CollectionCreated">
      <arg type="o" name="collection"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="CollectionDeleted">
      <arg type="o" name="collection"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="CollectionChanged">
      <arg type="o" name="collection"/>
    </signal>
    <property type="ao" name="Collections" access="read"/>
  </interface>
  <node name="collection"/>
</node>
"
Workbench can't find libproj.so, some options may be unavailable.

(process:18755): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:53:52.113: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = '/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench'
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench',
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f53e4ffedc0 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Se puede ver que hay varios errores, pero el principal es este:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Contenido de `/usr/bin/mysql-workbench`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Uncomment the following line if you're having trouble with gnome-keyring lockups.
# This will cause passwords to be stored only temporarily for the session.
#WB_NO_GNOME_KEYRING=1

# force disable the Mac style single menu hack in Ubuntu Unity
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0

# another Ubuntu bug, this this one causes modal dialogs to not work as intended
# https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/903302
export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0

# force x11 backend on systems that use wayland
export GDK_BACKEND=x11

# Set the destdir=<some_dir> when ever you install using DESTDIR=<some_dir>. 
destdir="$WB_DEST_DIR"

wblibdir="$destdir/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench"
wbpluginsdir="$destdir/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins"

# Check if PROJSO env is set and file exists, if not, try to handle this on our own
if [[ -z "${PROJSO}" ]]; then
  # Set the PROJSO env variable so gdal can find proj cause it's using dlopen instead ld 
  TMPLOC=`ldconfig -p | grep libproj\.so | awk '{printf $4;exit;}'`
  if [[ -f "$TMPLOC" ]]; then
    echo "Found $TMPLOC"
    export PROJSO=$TMPLOC
  else
    echo "Workbench can't find libproj.so, some options may be unavailable."
  fi
else
  if [[ ! -f ${PROJSO} ]]; then
    echo "PROJSO is set to ${PROJSO} but the library doesn't exist, some option may be unavailable."
  else
    echo "Using ${PROJSO}."
  fi
fi

if test -f $wblibdir/libsqlite3.so; then
  if test "$LD_PRELOAD" != ""; then
    export LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD:$wblibdir/libsqlite3.so"
  else
    export LD_PRELOAD="$wblibdir/libsqlite3.so"
  fi
fi


# if libcairo and pixman are in the wb libraries dir, force them to be preloaded
if test -f $wblibdir/libcairo.so.2; then
    if test "$LD_PRELOAD" != ""; then
        export LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD:$wblibdir/libcairo.so.2"
    else
        export LD_PRELOAD="$wblibdir/libcairo.so.2"
    fi
fi
if test -f $wblibdir/libpixman-1.so.0; then
    if test "$LD_PRELOAD" != ""; then
        export LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD:$wblibdir/libpixman.so.0"
    else
        export LD_PRELOAD="$wblibdir/libpixman.so.0"
    fi
fi


if test "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" != ""; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$wblibdir:$wbpluginsdir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
else
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$wblibdir:$wbpluginsdir"
fi

if test "$PYTHONPATH" != ""; then
    export PYTHONPATH="/usr/bin"
else
    export PYTHONPATH="/usr/bin"
fi

export MWB_DATA_DIR="$destdir/usr/share/mysql-workbench"
export MWB_LIBRARY_DIR="$destdir/usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries"
export MWB_MODULE_DIR="$destdir/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/modules"
export MWB_PLUGIN_DIR="$destdir/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/plugins"
export DBC_DRIVER_PATH="$destdir/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench"
export MWB_BASE_DIR="$destdir/usr"
export MWB_BINARIES_DIR="$destdir/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench"
export MWBX_JSMODULES_DIR=""

CAIRO=`ldd $MWB_BINARIES_DIR/mysql-workbench-bin | grep libcairo\.so | cut -d " " -f 3`
PNG=`ldd $CAIRO | grep libpng | cut -d " " -f 3`
LIBZ=`ldd $PNG | grep libz\.so | cut -d " " -f 3`


if test "$LD_PRELOAD" != ""; then
  export LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD:$LIBZ"
else
  export LD_PRELOAD="$LIBZ"
fi


if test "$WB_DEBUG" != ""; then
  $WB_DEBUG $MWB_BINARIES_DIR/mysql-workbench-bin "$@"
else
  if type -p catchsegv > /dev/null; then
  catchsegv $MWB_BINARIES_DIR/mysql-workbench-bin "$@"
  else
  $MWB_BINARIES_DIR/mysql-workbench-bin "$@"
  fi
fi
```

¿Cómo resuelvo esto?

Comment: por curiosidad, como se llama tu archivo que hace el `import` del modulo?

Comment: @Christian En verdad no lo sé, ¿Cómo puedo averiguarlo?

Comment: no tienes un script? ósea solo ejecutas `mysql-workbench`?

Comment: @Christian Ejecuto `mysql-workbench` sin argumentos.

Comment: Ha.. pensé que habías creado un script, no soy experto en eso, pero haz realizado alguna instalación o modificación de algo referente a workbench?

Comment: @Christian Sí, lo instalé varias veces con diferentes versiones pero no pude ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que no salga el error del `encodings` hay que reinstalar *Python 3*, en mi caso uso `slackpkg`:

```
slackpkg install python3
```